# mySQL query to show which ID's have specific records

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the vague title, not sure how else to describe it

Basically I have a table like this (cars separated by ^^)

```
id| cars 
-------------------------
 1|car1 ^^ car2 ^^ car3
 2|car2 ^^ car3
 3|car1
 4|car1 ^^ car 2
 5|car3
```

Basically I want to list all the cars with the id's they match to like this

```
car |id
-------------
car1|1,3,4
car2|1,2,4
car3|1,2,5
```

Is this possible to do in mySQL and what would be the query for it?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: please show us some code or pseudocode of what you have tried so far

Comment: Im not very well versed in mySQL  but

SELECT cars, id
FROM table_name
GROUP BY cars

I havent tried much because I cant think of what would work

Comment: `(cars separated by ^^)` Fix that, then get back to us.

Comment: When you say fix that, do you mean change it to something else?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I am using a table variable  "@Cars" to populate my result, However, you can replace that with actual table name that you have in your database.

```
--Table Defination:
    DECLARE @Cars TABLE
    (ID   INT IDENTITY,
     Cars VARCHAR(255)
    );
    INSERT INTO @Cars(Cars)
    VALUES('car1 ^^ car2 ^^ car3');
    INSERT INTO @Cars(Cars)
    VALUES('car2 ^^ car3');
    INSERT INTO @Cars(Cars)
    VALUES('car1');
    INSERT INTO @Cars(Cars)
    VALUES('car1 ^^ car2');
    INSERT INTO @Cars(Cars)
    VALUES('car3');

--SQL
    SELECT distinct Cars, STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT ', '+CAST([id] AS NVARCHAR(256))
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT A.id,
                               LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS Cars
                        FROM
                        (
                            SELECT ID,
                                   CAST('<M>'+REPLACE(Cars, '^^', '</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS String
                            FROM @Cars
                        ) AS A
                        CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/M') AS Split(a)
                    ) T1
                    WHERE T1.Cars = T2.Cars
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT A.id,
               LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS Cars
        FROM
        (
            SELECT ID,
                   CAST('<M>'+REPLACE(Cars, '^^', '</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS String
            FROM @Cars
        ) AS A
        CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/M') AS Split(a)
    ) T2;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply
I wish I could debug this my self by its a little advanced for me
This is the error I am getting


[id] AS NVARCHAR(256)) FROM ( ' at line 3

Comment: Is this a Sql server syntax?

Comment: I don't get any error, i have added table variable definitions which i use for creating a table.